# How do I make @click of a div that is receiving looped data of an API the div popups a window showing the rest of the keys in each object in the API

Tags: javascript, api, vue.js, object, vuex

```
<div 
  :style="image"
  class="main-browse">
  <div
    class="names"
    v-for="(user) in getUsers" 
    :key="user.id">
    <div
      id='user'
      :style="{backgroundColor: getColors}">
      <div>{{user.name}}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

The div with {{user.name}} when clicked I want it to show the rest of the details in the Api like user.email, user.occupation, in a new window,  Api data is coming from store.

am still new to vuex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `click` event listener to `div` with `.native` modifier if you are using Vue 2 or without if you are using Vue 3 ([docs](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/v-on-native-modifier-removed.html#v-on-native-modifier-removed)). In event handler function open your app in a new window with the proper route path.

```
<div 
  :style="image"
  class="main-browse"
>
  <div
    class="names"
    v-for="(user) in getUsers" 
    :key="user.id"
  >
    <div
      id='user'
      :style="{backgroundColor: getColors}"
      @click="clickHandler"
    >
      <div>{{user.name}}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
...
methods: {
  clickHandler () {
    const url = new URL(window.location.href); 
    // there you can edit your current location or leave it as it is
    window.open(url.href, '_blank'); 
  }
}
...
```

Also you can append to your route an `id` of an instance you want to display info about (e.g. *'mySuperApp.com/users/232344'*). Then you obtain it by calling in your component `$route.params.id` and then retrieve info from your `Vuex store` by that user id.

Comment: okay, though say i obtained the data from my routre and used in component,,,so i want the @click of a div  to open that component but only the item with the same id as the div?.

Comment: Because right now when i click all the contents of that component come yet i only want one thing with the same if